# Google Script: Can't able to access gs file data from html file while loading from URL

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to access my .gs file data(return from Public URL) from my html file. But it got return null all the time. But when I put logger on gs script it shows all the data. Can anyone please help me out.

**.gs file**

```
function getData() {

 var url = 'https://mydomain/getdetail';
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

 return response;

}
```

**.html file**

```
function onSuccess(data) {
  console.log(data);
}

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getData();
```

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to fetch?  You might want to check [these restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values)

Comment: I'd recommend providing the server side code as well.  Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: I just noticed that the name of your function is `getData()` in the gs file but your calling it witth `fetchData()`

Comment: Have you tried, return response.getContentText();

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. But this is not the problem.I'll change my code

Comment: As asked before, *Have you tried, return response.getContentText();*? Republish the app with a new version to reflect code modifications

Comment: Did you solve it? If not, please, update the question.